# How to show ticks on y axis on frequency plot?

Tags: r

I have a code like this, which produces attached plot. My question is how to show the exact value on y axis for values on x axis which are 1 and 2. Also how would I change text on x and y axis? And how to make y axis go to 10000.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
a=fread("ukb_all_add.txt")
a=select(a,V3,V12)
a=na.omit(a)
colnames(a)=c("rs","pvalue")

# A blank data frame to hold the data you want to plot
plotData = data.frame(
     n = as.integer(),
     sample = as.character(),
     propfdr = as.double()
)

# Loop through 10000 times as an example
for (n in 1: 10000) {
     # create 'b' as a list of 30 points to take from a
     b <- sample ( 1 : length (a$rs), 30, replace = F )
     # put the 30 values of interest from a into c

     c <- a[ b , ]

     # do your stats
     c$fdr <- p.adjust ( c$pvalue, method = "BH" )

     # capture what you did
     mySample <- paste(b, collapse= ",")
     thisRow <- data.frame(
         n = as.integer(n),
         sample = as.character(mySample),
         fdrlt5 = as.integer(length(c$fdr[c$fdr<0.05]))
     )

     # merge this row into the data
     plotData <- rbind(
         plotData,
         thisRow
     )
}

hist(plotData$fdrlt5)
```

[image]

the output of:

```
dput(hist(plotData$fdrlt5))

structure(list(breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 
1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3), counts = c(9543L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 419L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 33L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L), density = c(4.7715, 
0, 0, 0, 0.2095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0165, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0025), mids = c(0.1, 
0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 
2.9), xname = "plotData$fdrlt5", equidist = TRUE), class = "histogram")
List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:16] 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 ...
 $ counts  : int [1:15] 9543 0 0 0 419 0 0 0 0 33 ...
 $ density : num [1:15] 4.77 0 0 0 0.21 ...
 $ mids    : num [1:15] 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9 1.1 1.3 1.5 1.7 1.9 ...
 $ xname   : chr "plotData$fdrlt5"
 $ equidist: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

Comment: I just noticed that you tagged this with [tag:ggplot2]. Is there a reason you did that yet use base-graphics in your example?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I was hoping to use it but I didn't. I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

The `hist` function returns enough information to do that.

```r
h <- hist(mtcars$disp)
str(h)
# List of 6
#  $ breaks  : int [1:10] 50 100 150 200 250 300 350 400 450 500
#  $ counts  : int [1:9] 5 7 4 1 4 4 4 1 2
#  $ density : num [1:9] 0.003125 0.004375 0.0025 0.000625 0.0025 ...
#  $ mids    : num [1:9] 75 125 175 225 275 325 375 425 475
#  $ xname   : chr "mtcars$disp"
#  $ equidist: logi TRUE
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

So you can use `$mids` for the x-value (mid point of each bar) and `$counts` for the y-value.

```r
text(h$mids, h$counts, h$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
```

[image: first histogram with text clipping]

As you can see, though, this does allow *clipping* of some labels (depending on the data). This can be mitigated by first determining what the y-limits should be, then plotting with the right limits.

```r
h <- hist(mtcars$disp, plot = FALSE)
range(h$counts)
# [1] 1 7
h <- hist(mtcars$disp, ylim = c(0, 8))
text(h$mids, h$counts, h$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
```

[image: second histogram without clipping]

Then to address the rest of your questions:

- change y axis to go to 10000 (I'll use "10") here:

  ```r
  h <- hist(mtcars$disp, ylim = c(0, 10), yaxt = "n")
  axis(2, at = seq(0, 10, by = 2), labels = seq(0, 10, by = 2), las = 1)
  ```

  (I added `las = 1` to rotate the axis labels. In general, I think rotating the numbers as such can be good, but also R will at times drop axis labels when there is not enough space for all of them, so it can be more important. Ways to mitigate this include `las=` as here and `cex.axis=0.9` or some lower positive number.)
- just some columns?

  ```r
  text(h$mids[1:2], h$counts[1:2], h$counts[1:2], adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
  ```

[image: extended histogram]

---

I don't know why things are breaking for you on your console. I'll use the output from `hist` to regenerate the histogram as a manual barplot. This is not ideal, but it works for me. (I increased the y-axis to 11000 solely because of the dimensions of this small plot for SO, it should not be needed in general.)

```r
h2 <- hist(plotData$fdrlt5, plot = FALSE)
plot(NA, type='n', xlim=range(h2$mids)+c(-0.1,0.1),
     ylim=c(0,11000), frame.plot=F, xlab="Proportion", ylab="Frequency", yaxt="n")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), labels = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), las=1)
rect(h2$mids-0.1, 0, h2$mids+0.1, h2$counts)
text(h2$mids[1:2], h2$counts[1:2], h2$counts[1:2], adj=c(0.5, -0.5))
```

[image: manual barplot-histogram]

Comment: Hi, thank you for this elaborate answer I tried to add this on the end of my code: h <- hist(plotData$fdrlt5,plot = FALSE)
range(h$counts)
h <- hist(plotData$fdrlt5, ylim = c(0, 10000))
text(h$mids, h$counts, h$counts, adj=c(0.5, -0.5)) but this didn't change anything on my plot.

Comment: I also tried the first idea and I got this:List of 6
 $ breaks  : num [1:16] 0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 ...
 $ counts  : int [1:15] 9535 0 0 0 434 0 0 0 0 27 ...
Does this mean there are 9535 of those that have value 1 on x axis and 434 have value 2? I just basically need this information

Comment: That is correct. In [`?hist`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html), in the "Values" section, it defines all of the list components, including: *"counts: n integers; for each cell, the number of 'x[]' inside"*.

Comment: I am sorry to bother, I did add this  on teh end of my code and it still didn't change anything on the plot h <- hist(plotData$fdrlt5,ylim = c(0, 10000), yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), labels = seq(0, 10000, by = 1000), las = 1)
text(h$mids[1:2], h$counts[1:2], h$counts[1:2], adj=c(0.5, -0.5))  Can you please tell me what modification in code would just output on command line values of y for x=1 and x=2

Comment: That code works for me (adapted for `mtcars$disp` and a y limit of 10). Please be clear and specific: what is not working for you? What are the values of `h$mids[1:2]` and `h$counts[1:2]`? (Since the question is not fully reproducible, I'm stuck with what I have and what I know.)

Comment: well I would like to put on y axis exactly the frequency equivalent to x~1 and x~2 and (those values seem to be for me 415 and 27 from your str(h) example) Also I would like to change the names of x and y axis, say y axis "permutation" and x axis "proportion"

Comment: I don't understand, as on my plots I see the counts "5" and "7" at the top of the first and second histogram bars.

Comment: Can you add the output from `dput(hist(...))` to your question?

Comment: I just tried your code and it gave me 9548 above the first bar (around x=0) what I need are the numbers over the second two bars (around x=1 and x=2) can you please edit your code so that it shows that

Comment: Just replace `1:2` with `2:3` in the call to `text`. But certainly the premise is answered: how to put labels over some subset of the bars. Just index the `$mids` and `$counts` accordingly.

Comment: anamaria, does this answer your question? If so, please accept it! If not, please update your question accordingly. Thanks!